# Twilio Disconnection event not firing on IOS

Tags: objective-c, cordova, twilio

I'm creating mobile app based on **Twilio** and **Cordova** (https://github.com/jefflinwood/twilio_client_phonegap), it works well, but I seem to have a problem with connection events.

The problem is `ConnectionDelegate` callback `connectionDidDisconnect` doesnt seem to be fired in some situations. For example:

- User 1 is calling from browser
- User 2 anwsers on iPhone/Android/Browser
- They talk
- User 1 hangs up in browser
- User 2 will get disconnection event on every other device than iPhone. On iPhone callback `connectionDidDisconnect` is not called at all.

Another situation:

- User 1 is calling from browser
- User 2 anwsers on iPhone/Android/Browser
- They talk
- User 2 hangs up
- User 2 will get disconnection event on every other device than iPhone. On iPhone callback `connectionDidDisconnect` is not called at all.

Could you tell me where I'm making mistake?

**UPDATE:**

- When user anwsered incoming call on iPhone and caller hangs up I get `[ERROR TCMetricsPublisher] Failed to push call stats, status code: 403` error.
- When user anwsered incoming call on iPhone and he hangs up, nothing happends.

Answer (score 0):

From [others experience](https://github.com/jefflinwood/twilio_client_phonegap/issues) using the same plugin, it seems you can solve the issue by using the `status` callback that Twilio handles when the call ends. [Modify the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state) from parameters and set the `status` to "completed" for this call.

Doing this should allow the call to [disconnect properly on iOS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios/TCConnectionDelegate#connectionDidDisconnect).

Please let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks! I will test that if my current soultion wont be working as it supposed to. Using wamp socket server (I have it already for in-app-notifications) Im creating another channel of communication between users and my server. And server is reciving status updates form twilio via action and status callback.

`<Dial action="https://api.example.com/twilio/status/call/98" timeLimit="300" callerId="85">
        <Client statusCallback="https://api.example.com/twilio/status/call/98">user44</Client>
    </Dial>`
(I have my own entites for each call)

Comment: I have tested both my way and your way, unfortunatlly its the same. No matter if I try disconnect via `disconnectAll()` or by modifing ongoing call via api I still get the same: event `connectionDidDisconnect` is not fired.

Comment: `connectionDidDisconnect` is also not fired on `connection.disconnect()`

Comment: For now, as workaround for this bug, I've returned to extra socket connection for each call to send some informations. First version with socket based on `Device.disconnectAll()`, now it does not use Twilio event at all, it fires the function itself.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It would probably help to have this discussion with the project creator on github as well.

Comment: The problem is I have checked his code, added some logs direclty to delegate methods and Im pretty sure that something is not right in twilio client lib. Anyway, it works with this workaround for now.